# test if strstr return a valid pointer

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to use strstr function like this:

```
const char * pInicio = strstr(origem, chave);       
if (pInicio != NULL) ...
```

Contrary to the expected, when I do the "if" test the compiler throws a access position violation exception. It occurs everytime I try to get some key word that doesn't exist from a string.

The call stack is:

```
    ntdll.dll!779315de()    
    [Os quadros abaixo podem estar incorretos e/ou ausentes, nenhum símbolo foi carregado para ntdll.dll]   
    ntdll.dll!779315de()    
    ntdll.dll!7792014e()    
>   msvcr100d.dll!_output_l(_iobuf * stream, const char * format, localeinfo_struct * plocinfo, char * argptr)  Linha 2361 + 0xa bytes  C++
    cccccccc()
```

The output was:

```
Exceção de primeira chance em 0x0f8620a7 (msvcr100d.dll) no TestesApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Violação de acesso ao ler o local 0x00000001.
Exceção sem-tratamento em 0x779315de no TestesApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Violação de acesso ao ler o local 0x00000001.
```

Right before the exception, the variable values were:

1. chave: 0x00196f64 "$GNGSA"  type:char *
2. Origem: 0x00196840 "$GPRMC,000651.082,V,,,,,,,191210,,,N*4F                             $GPGGA,000652.091,,,,,0,00,,,M,0.0,M,,0000*5F                               $GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E"   type:const char *
3. pInicio: 0x00000000  invalid>  type:const char *

The linker command line is:

```
/OUT:"C:\Users\Leandro\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TestesApp\Debug\TestesApp.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /MANIFEST /ManifestFile:"Debug\TestesApp.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ALLOWISOLATION /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"C:\Users\Leandro\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TestesApp\Debug\TestesApp.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /PGD:"C:\Users\Leandro\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TestesApp\Debug\TestesApp.pgd" /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE
```

also the c/c++ command line is

```
/ZI /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fp"Debug\TestesApp.pch" /Fa"Debug\" /Fo"Debug\" /Fd"Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd /analyze- /errorReport:queue
```

After this, I try to test the pointer if it is null.
That is my problem now, how to solve this?

Best regards!

Comment: Doesn't look like it is in this code. Are you sure the parameters to `strstr` are valid?

Comment: Are you sure the error is happening on the `if` line?

Comment: If you're getting an access violation from `strstr()`, either the addresses your passing in are not valid, or the strings they're referencing are not terminated. I suggest you validate both conditions *before* concluding something is wrong with the above code.

Comment: yeah, I'm debugging the code and it happens on if line.

Comment: The parameters to strstr are valid. The string chave was correctly initialized at the scope of the function and origem is used other times and is ok in these times.

Comment: What I can add to these informations is that when throw the exception, the code stop at tidtable.c file in the function: _CRTIMP PFLS_GETVALUE_FUNCTION __cdecl __set_flsgetvalue()

Comment: Please provide the complete stack trace of the exception, along with the values of "origem" and "chave". Can you please also add a dummy printf("hello\r\n"); right before the "if" and verify where the exception occurs?

Comment: Ok, the complete stack and information about variables is now in the body of the question.

Comment: Have you tried it without the `const` qualifier?  It appears that there's an issue assigning the `NULL` value to your variable.

Comment: I tryed to remove the const qualifier. It didn't change anything. Also I put the printf before the if statement and it is printing correctly.

Comment: Post definition and population of origem and chave.

Comment: Yes, please post enough code so we may duplicate your issue.  Also, are you compiling with any special switches/settings or libraries attached/enabled?  Assume you're building for C++, let us know if you're using plain C instead.  Anything might be relevant.  (Been trying with what you've provided in VS2010 but unable to duplicate so far.)

Comment: char * chave = "$GNGSA";
const char * origem =  "$GPRMC,000651.082,V,,,,,,,191210,,,N*4F\r\n\        $GPGGA,000652.091,,,,,0,00,,,M,0.0,M,,0000*5F\r\n\        $GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E";

Comment: It's a C code, a .c file compiled at VisualStudio 2010. How can I don't understand much more from VS, I didn't change any configuration just save the file as a .c rather than cpp

Comment: Honestly the only thing so far I see wrong with your code is the non-const pointer declaration for `char * chave = "$GNGSA";`. That pointer should be `const char *chave`. But that should not cause what you're describing. Given proper parameters and enough stack space (which isn't much) there is no earthly reason `strstr()` should be returning anything invalid, and most certainly no reason performing effectively a `jz` (jump on zero) immediately thereafter.

Answer (score 2):

Cannot duplicate your bug.  Here's what I tried:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
   char * chave = "$GNGSA";
   const char * origem = "$GPRMC,000651.082,V,,,,,,,191210,,,N*4F $GPGGA,000652.091,,,,,0,00,,,M,0.0,M,,0000*5F $GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E";
   const char * pInicio = strstr(origem, chave);
   if (pInicio != NULL)
   {
      printf("found it\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

This compiles and runs without error in Visual Studio 2010.  It does not find a match, by the way.  I'm open to instructions on how to adjust it to create the bug.

--edit--

Set compiler command line to:  /ZI /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fp"Debug\odt.pch" /Fa"Debug\" /Fo"Debug\" /Fd"Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd /analyze- /errorReport:queue

Linker command line:  /OUT:"E:\code\odt\Debug\odt.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /MANIFEST /ManifestFile:"Debug\odt.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ALLOWISOLATION /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"E:\code\odt\Debug\odt.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /PGD:"E:\code\odt\Debug\odt.pgd" /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE

Even with both command lines essentially the same, I am still not getting the error.  I don't know what to say, sorry.

Comment: But it is exactly what I'm doing. Some the I noticed is that c compiler in VS2010 is C89. There is any problem with this?

Comment: Perhaps it would help me if you could look at your project settings and post the command line for C/C++ and Linker.  I can enter them as mine to be sure I'm building like you are.

Comment: I tryed to do the same and believe it didn't work! I even put an else statement with a printf("didn't found") and it printed it.

Comment: the command line is: /ZI /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fp"Debug\TestesApp.pch" /Fa"Debug\" /Fo"Debug\" /Fd"Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd /analyze- /errorReport:queue

Comment: humm...now I see that its ok in this test. I tryed it here and it returns ok. The problem occurs in that part of the code. I'll try some changes here...

Comment: Good luck.  One thing to watch:  your project is being built for UNICODE but you are using `char` which might not be portable and some string functions might not work correctly for you if you use a UNICODE function on an ASCII string or vice-versa.